# Choosing MSVC toolchain

Tags: qt, visual-c++, qt-creator

I want to use QtCreator and MSVC as a compiler instead of MinGW. I successfully compiled Qt source code with MSVC 2010. As you would have guessed, I have MSVC 2010 installed on my machine. I also registered MSVC version of Qt in QtCreator, but now the problem is that I can’t select MSVC toolchain in qtcreator. 
So far, I found out that QT_INSTALL_LIBS and QT_INSTALL_BINS are not correctly configured for MSVC version of qt binaries. I guess this could be the problem, but I don’t know how I should configure that variables.

Here's the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have define the environment variable QTDIR (this can be done in command line, using **set** command). This allows Qt Creator to auto-detect the value.

Also, could you try to rename the folder not using 'c++', instead use e.g. 'cplusplus', and see if this could also resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `QMAKESPEC` environment variable to "win32-msvc2010" (or create the variable if you don't have it), then restart QtCreator. This tells Qt and QtCreator that you are using the msvc compiler of Visual Studio 2010 for 32bit windows applications.

That should do the trick.

PS: If you have any Windows Explorer windows open you need to close these too after setting the environment variable.
PPS: Press [windows-key][Pause] to quickly access the system properties dialog